# Orthonormal basis of the Fourier Transform

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, orthonormal

I am currently writing a small paper regarding the analogy between Fourier analysis and linear algebra for my mathematics class. Unfortunately, I am stuck at proving that $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{t}\omega t}$ forms an orthonormal basis in the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ for all $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$.

In my paper I already showed that $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i} n/T}\in L^2([-T/2;T/2])$ forms an orthonormal basis for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
\langle \mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i} n/T},\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i} m/T}\rangle=\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i} n/T}\overline{\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i} m/T}}\mathrm{d}t=\delta_{nm}.
$$
Therefore, the Fourier series of a function $f(t)\in L^2([-T/2;T/2])$ can be interpreted as an orthogonal projection of $f$ onto the individual basis functions with
$$
f(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\underbrace{\left\langle f(t),\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i} kt/T}\right\rangle}_{=c_k} \mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i} kt/T}
$$
When we extend the Fourier series to a non-periodic function $f(t)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we get the Fourier transform and the inverse Fourier transform give by
$$
f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(\omega)\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i} \omega t}\mathrm{d}\omega, \quad \hat{f}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\mathrm{e}^{-2\pi\mathrm{i}\omega t}\mathrm{d}t
$$
In order for the Fourier transform to work I would assume that $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{t}\omega t}$ also has to form an orthonormal basis for each $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$ in the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. But can we prove something like
$$
\forall \omega_1,\omega_2\in\mathbb{R}\colon \langle \mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i} \omega_1},\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i} \omega_2}\rangle=\delta_{\omega_1\omega_2}
$$
And if so, how could I prove it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See Eq. 1.17.12 [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.17).